# PHP password_hash Check Two Hashes

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, password-hash, php-password-hash

If I have a two password hashes created using [`password_hash`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, how can I tell if they came from the same base password? I know it uses a different salt each time. I do not have the plain text.

For instance:
`$2y$10$M6CnjqaxuUKNhg84T8NpLeylkUrvP1pzoZNhBWfpSzP2zJneuS1re` and `$2y$10$ZSlQNIbsLWfj7JLCSkvFLeS/adH.KnGZTgA1BcvyPXl7BEn7GhREO` both came from hashing `test`. How can I write a function that will return true if given these two hashes as parameters?

Is this possible?

So:

```
<?php
function check_hashes($hash1, $hash2) {
(some code)
}
echo strval(check_hashes('$2y$10$M6CnjqaxuUKNhg84T8NpLeylkUrvP1pzoZNhBWfpSzP2zJneuS1re', '$2y$10$ZSlQNIbsLWfj7JLCSkvFLeS/adH.KnGZTgA1BcvyPXl7BEn7GhREO'));
echo strval(check_hashes('$2y$10$ZSlQNIbsLWfj7JLCSkvFLeS/adH.KnGZTgA1BcvyPXl7BEn7GhREO', '$2y$10$LoUOu3kt7zm1YZI1PtAsD.yzWF0b9jqOaAH64lK51VtgqRJZBgtO6'));
?>
```

Would output:

```
TRUE
FALSE
```

Comment: Did you read this? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, you can not check if the two hashes belong to the same password, unless you already know the password. If you could, this basically fails the purpose of using the `password_hash` function.**

If you know the password, you can simply, use the method: [`password_verify`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify your passwords:

```
$res1 = "$2y$10$ZSlQNIbsLWfj7JLCSkvFLeS/adH.KnGZTgA1BcvyPXl7BEn7GhREO";
$res2 = "$2y$10$M6CnjqaxuUKNhg84T8NpLeylkUrvP1pzoZNhBWfpSzP2zJneuS1re";
var_dump(password_verify("test", $res1)); // returns true
var_dump(password_verify("test", $res2)); // returns true
```

So, as you can see, both the hashes will give you `true` with `password_verify()` method, and therefore, you do not need to check if the two hashes belong to the same password or not. And, if you do, the above logic can be used to construct a function like this:

```
function belongs_to_password() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  $str  = array_shift($args);
  foreach ($args as $hash) {
    if (!password_verify($str, $hash)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

The above function can be used to check whether the hashes passed to this function are all for the same password or not. And, can be used like this:

```
$res1 = "$2y$10$ZSlQNIbsLWfj7JLCSkvFLeS/adH.KnGZTgA1BcvyPXl7BEn7GhREO";
$res2 = "$2y$10$M6CnjqaxuUKNhg84T8NpLeylkUrvP1pzoZNhBWfpSzP2zJneuS1re";
var_dump(belong_to_password("test", $res1, $res2)); // returns true
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was clear. I meant If I didn't know that `test` was the base string. Given only the two hashes is it still possible to tell if they came from the same base?

Comment: @735Tesla: Yes, I understand, and as I said in my answer, you need to know your base string.

Comment: @Stoic Thanks. Knowing that the salt is a function of the first bits of the hash is there a quicker way to figure out than just brute forcing both of them?

Comment: @735Tesla: Unless, you know the `base string`, I doubt anything other than brute force will help you. I doubt, even if that can!

Answer (score 3):

The information about the salt and hash methodology is encoded into the hash. This allow `password_verify()` to work without separate knowledge of the salt (i.e. you don't need to store the salt in a database somewhere).

Note this section from `pasword_verify()` documentation:

> Note that password_hash() returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the verify function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

As such, you can simply run `password_verify()` against both hashes.

```
$hash1_verified = password_verify('test', $hash1);
$hash2_verified = password_verify('test', $hash2);
```

If both of these return true, they are both hashes of `test`.

A function for comparing a base word against an arbitrarily-sized array of hashes to verify all hashes come from that same base word might look like this:

```
function hash_base_matches_all_hashes($base, $hash_array) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($hash_array); $i++) {
        if (false === password_verify($base, $hash_array[$i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was clear. I meant If I didn't know that `test` was the base string. Given only the two hashes is it still possible to tell if they came from the same base?

Comment: @735Tesla No it is not possible to test with knowing the base string.  That is the intention of one-way hashing.