# How to compare two different hashed passwords

Tags: php

I am trying to compare two different hashed passwords, I am going to use this when a user resets his password, so I can check if the two hashes passwords are equal or not. I heard that this was unsafe so how do I make it safe? I don't really have any sample code. Originally I thought I can just "unhash" both passwords but seems like you can't really "unhash" a hashed password. You can verify them but that's not exactly what I wanted. Can anyone help?

Best Regards,
cyphenom

Comment: Depends on hashing method and salt usage.

Comment: @u_mulder, I'm using the PASSWORD_DEFAULT hash

Comment: Can't you use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)? You give it the new password, and use the hash of the old password. If it returns `true` you know it's the same password.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware never thought of it like that, lemme try that really quickly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP password\_hash Check Two Hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805178/php-password-hash-check-two-hashes)

Answer (score 1):

So, as you can see, both the hashes will give you true with password_verify() method, and therefore, you do not need to check if the two hashes belong to the same password or not. And, if you do, the above logic can be used to construct a function like this:

```
 function belongs_to_password() {
      $args = func_get_args();
      $str  = array_shift($args);
      foreach ($args as $hash) {
        if (!password_verify($str, $hash)) return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

The above function can be used to check whether the hashes passed to this function are all for the same password or not. And, can be used like this:

```
$res1 = "$2y$10$ZSlQNIbsLWfj7JLCSkvFLeS/adH.KnGZTgA1BcvyPXl7BEn7GhREO";
$res2 = "$2y$10$M6CnjqaxuUKNhg84T8NpLeylkUrvP1pzoZNhBWfpSzP2zJneuS1re";
var_dump(belong_to_password("test", $res1, $res2)); // returns true
```

Comment: I used to same logic but its not necessary to build a function like that, just get the row which has the hashes password and then verify it to the input.